# C# How to force Paint event of Panel1 and Panel2 complete at the same time?

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, paint, splitcontainer

I have a SplitContainer (a [NonFlickerSplitContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859504/c-sharp-windows-forms-splitter-flickering#22011809) one to be exact) and I treat its both panels as a single canvas to paint on. I use Graphics.DrawImage method to paint bitmaps on the panels separately. I refresh Panel1 first, then Panel2 which results in vertical/horizontal tearing - painting of Panel1 ends, then painting of Panel2 starts - that's the reason. What would be the solution to my problem? I use a splitContainer as an output to a "bitmap video stream" with before/after capability. Maybe I can freeze UI somehow until Panel2_Paint ends?

```
    private void splitContainer_Panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (frameA != null)
        {
            if (ORIGINAL_SIZE_SET)
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(frameA, 0, 0);
            else
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(frameA, 0, 0, ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
        }
    }

    private void splitContainer_Panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (frameB != null)
        {
            //...

            if (ORIGINAL_SIZE_SET)
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(frameB, x, y);
            else
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(frameB, x, y, ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
        }
    }

    private Bitmap frameA = null;
    private Bitmap frameB = null;

    private void RefreshOutput(bool refreshClipA = true, bool refreshClipB = true)
    {
        if (refreshClipA)
        {
            frameA = GetVideoFrame(...);

            //...
        }

        if (refreshClipB)
        {
            frameB = GetVideoFrame(...);

            //...
        }

        if (refreshClipA)
            splitContainer.Panel1.Refresh();

        if (refreshClipB)
            splitContainer.Panel2.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: I would appreciate a method that could freeze the splitcontainer until I say it can resume again. I assume there is no such method, though. The dirty way to do it could be overlaying a picturebox with the previous bitmap over the Panel1 unitl Panel2_Paint ends, right? Ain't it too dirty and inefficient to consider?

Comment: You probably can't force two panels to paint at the same time. I'm using a single panel to paint on now. I take portions of bitmaps and draw them on the panel. I'm treating Mouse_Click as the previous Splitter_Moved event. This is a more efficient solution. If You have the same problem as I did, ditch SplitContainer in the first place. I didn't write it but I had found a way to paint at the same time before  I asked this question - don't use it though as it is absolutely a very dirty and glitchy approach. I had docked two PictureBoxes on both Panel1 and Panel2 and had used its Image property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced it is impossible to make sure that two separate panel.Paint() events complete at the same moment, at least not in a WinForms project. The only solution that worked for me is the suggested by DonBoitnott. I use a single panel now and simulate a splitcontainer behavior.

> If I were answering this, I would suggest you ditch the splitcontainer and render to a single surface, that way you are always in a single Paint event and you simply region it off and draw accordingly. – **DonBoitnott** Feb 17 '16 at 17:51

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation for [`SplitContainer.Invalidate(bool invalidate Children)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/xz8ytzt0(v=vs.90)).

From the link:

> Invalidates a specific region of the control and causes a paint message to be sent to the control. Optionally, invalidates the child controls assigned to the control.

So instead of invalidating each panel separately just call this method once and it should do what you want. Or to modify your code only a bit:

```
if (refreshClipA && refreshClipB)
{
    splitContainer.Invalidate(true);
}
else
{
    if (refreshClipA)
    {
        splitContainer.Panel1.Refresh();
    }
    else if (refreshClipB)
    {
        splitContainer.Panel2.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Essentially what I am doing is if both of them need repainting let `splitContainer` handle it, else check each one individually and paint if required.

Leading on from @DonBoitnott's comment, Instead of using `Invalidate(true)` use [`Refresh()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) which from the documentation:

> Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself and any child controls.

So just change `splitContainer.Invalidate(true)` to `splitContainer.Refresh()`.

Comment: Have been playing with Invalidate too. It doesn't seem to make a difference compared to separated refreshing. In addition it ruins my playback feature based upon a backgroundworker

Comment: @kagetoki You can't use threading to solve the issue because it will all have to be done on the UI thread so the only way of doing it is to let the parent control handle any drawing or live with it. If you're trying to make two video players side by side as well using panels and bitmaps is probably not the way to go

Comment: @kagetoki Alternatively if you know only a small portion of the image has changed you can repaint only a region of the panel

Comment: May the part about backgroundworker not mislead You. It doesn't split drawing into different threads, it cannot - the UI thread is only one. I invoke actions on UI, that's all I do to get auto playback. It doesn't matter, though. Still I can see tearing after just a single invalidate call started by a key press in UI event.

Comment: @kagetoki I know it was a comment of me saying that it can not be done that way, not that you were trying to do it that way

Comment: FYI, the difference lies in the difference between `Invalidate`:  "causes a paint message to be sent" and `Refresh`:  "Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself".  You have no control over when the control responds to the _request_ for a repaint.

Comment: @kagetoki Read DonBoitnott's comment try using `splitContainer.Refresh()` where I put `splitContainer.Invalidate(true)`

Comment: @DonBoitnott Are you saying my code 'should' be fine if I change `Invalidate(true)` to `Refresh()`?

Comment: It should respond quicker to the call for a repaint.

Comment: I tried refreshing/suspending different areas/controls in the past. None of the settings worked fine. Refreshing the splitcontainer instead of invalidating doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I wouldn't refresh the container...refresh both panels.  I think they are the drawing surfaces, not the container.  I.e. remove the outer if and just use the inner one, without the else, of course.

Comment: @DonBoitnott See the code in the question post. Refreshing the panels separately is what I'm originally doing.

Comment: @kagetoki I do see that.  If I were answering this, I would suggest you ditch the splitcontainer and render to a single surface, that way you are always in a single Paint event and you simply region it off and draw accordingly.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I'd suggest that but to answer the question as asked I did what I said

Comment: @DonBoitnott So I did in the end. I'm using a single panel to paint on now. A much more efficient solution than before solving my issues. Demanded much work, though.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe I can freeze UI somehow until Panel2_Paint ends?

Take a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout(v=vs.110).aspx

Call SuspendLayout() on your control, do all of your graphics operations and then call ResumeLayout() to update everything all at once.  There is an example in that documentation.

If your drawing operations take too long then temporary graphical artifacts mght begin to appear in the "frozen" area until after ResumeLayout().

Comment: I don't think the layout methods have anything to do with painting. They're to do with, you know, layout (size, position, etc). Admittedly, suspending layout will save some painting time for intermediate layout, *if you're changing layout related items*, but I don't think that's what the OP is talking about.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Oh, sorry about that.  I thought this would block all operations that affected the appearance including raster drawn regions.

Comment: Unfortunately suspending either the form's or the splicontainer's layout is not a solution. Have been checking it many times.